# Characterization of Discrete Valuation Rings

Tags: commutative-algebra

> Let $R$ be a Noetherian local domain with unique maximal ideal $M$. Then I want to show that if every $M$-primary ideal is a power of $M$, then $R$ is a Discrete Valuation Ring.

I know I'll be done if I can show that $M$ is principal, or that $M$ is the only prime ideal (since then I can invoke, or that $R$ is integrally closed in its field of fractions, but I'm not sure how to show any of those things. Could I have some hints?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Equivalent characterizations of discrete valuation rings](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2198198/equivalent-characterizations-of-discrete-valuation-rings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no ideal (properly) between $M^2$ and $M$ (why?). Let $x\in M-M^2$. (What can you say if $M=M^2$?) Then $M^2+(x)=M$, and from [Nakayama Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nakayama_lemma) get $M=(x)$.

Comment: Oh, so since any ideal contained between $M$ and $M^2$ has $M$ as its radical, it must then be $M$ or $M^2$? But this ideal between $M$ and $M^2$ doesn't have to be primary?

Comment: Okay, I think I got it: by primary decomposition, such an ideal is contained in the intersection of primary ideals, and thus in the intersection of the associated primes. But since the radical of this ideal is $M$, $M$ is the only prime that contains it, so this ideal is just an $M$-primary ideal, and thus just $M$ or $M^2$.

Comment: @Nishant In general, an ideal whose radical is a maximal ideal $M$ is necessarily $M$-primary.